# Why does this program give a Windows 8 SmartScreen warning?

Tags: windows-8, security, malware, malware-detection

Why does this program

http://creativeadept.com/download-spintax-editor/

give me a SmartScreen warning in Windows 8

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/jGyYD.png]

when a Malwarebytes scan and Windows Defender scan found nothing? What is wrong with the program? Other programs are not giving that warning.

The Wiki entry on SmartScreen only says it does reputation checks, but doesn't say what or how it checks.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_SmartScreen

> #### SmartScreen in Windows 8
>
> Windows 8 introduced SmartScreen filtering at the desktop level, performing reputation checks by default on any file or application downloaded from the Internet.[5][6] Microsoft faced concerns surrounding the privacy, legality and effectiveness of the new system; suggesting that the automatic analysis of files (which involves sending a cryptographic hash of the file and the user's IP address to a server) could be used to build a database of users' downloads online, and that the use of the outdated SSL 2.0 protocol for communication could allow an attacker to eavesdrop on the data. In response, Microsoft later issued a statement noting that IP addresses were only being collected as part of the normal operation of the service and would be periodically deleted, that SmartScreen on Windows 8 would only use SSL 3.0 for security reasons, and that information gathered via SmartScreen would not be used for advertising purposes or sold to third parties.[7]

Comment: Because its reputation is unknown.

Comment: @Ramhound Is it actually dangerous?

Comment: Spying programs apart, the MS long term strategy is not to allow anything they don't approve on their operating system. their biggest mistake was not to allow custom drivers wince Vista x64, and things go on and on.

Comment: @Chloe - You tell me?  I am just telling you the reason you are being warned about the file.  The reputation is unknown, `SmartScreen` will filter a file when it's reputation is either unknown or it's reputation is known and negative.  If you trust the author then the file is harmless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To actually answer, nothing is wrong with the program.
Microsoft will only allow well-known (popular/reputable/certified) applications to directly run/install without that warning. Any smaller less known application can generate such a message.